# Marionette passed objects to module

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I have recently updated to Marionette JS version 2.4.7 after being on an older version of Marionette for a very long time.

I am initializing a `module` and want to pass two objects to this `module`, a `model` and another custom object `foo`.

```
layout = new FooBar.Layout
  model: options.model if options.model
  foo: options.foo if options.foo
options.loadRegion.show(layout)
```

The model comes through just fine in the `initialize` method of the FooBar module but the `foo` object is not coming through in the `options` object of the FooBar module no matter what I try, though it is appearing in the `options` object before I initialize `FooBar.Layout` (as seen above).

Am I doing something wrong in the new version of Marionette?

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem was with trying to run a conditional statement in an object property declaration, which does not work.

```
layout = new FooBar.Layout
  model: options.model if options.model
  foo: options.foo if options.foo
```

Removing the conditional statements works:

```
layout = new FooBar.Layout
  model: options.model
  foo: options.foo
```

Or declaring your object before creating the new Layout works, as well

```
opts = nil
opts.model = options.model if options.model
opts.foo = options.foo if options.foo

layout = new FooBar.Layout(opts)
```